# waiting for swfobject.js to load gives me an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, swfobject, infinite-loop, externalinterface

I have a javascript script that uses SWFobject to embed a flash player.  When i got to embed the flash player with

```
swfobject.embedSWF(..)
```

i get an error reading that swfobject is undefined.  I believe this is happening because our website caches the javascript for my application but doesn't cache the swfobject.js file, so myApp.js, which calls swfobject.embedSWF(..) loads long before swfobject.js.  I currently can't change what's being cached, so i came up with this work around:

```
while(!$(that.mediaPlayer).find('#'+that.playerID)[0]){
     console.log(that.playerID+' not defined');
     that.embedFlashPlayer(1,1);
}

...

this.embedFlashPlayer = function (width, height){
    var that = this;
    var playerID =  that.playerID;
    var server = document.URL.replace(/^.*\/\//,'').replace(/\..*$/,'');
    var flashvars = {};
    var flashSrc = "/flash/AS3MediaPlayer.swf?server"+server+"&playerID="+playerID;

    //parameters
    var params = {};
    params.movie = flashSrc;
    params.quality = "high";
    params.play = "true";
    params.LOOP = "false";
    params.wmode = "transparent";

    //attributes
    var attr = {};
    attr.classid = "clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000";
    attr.codebase = "http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,16,0";
    attr.width = "" + width;
    attr.height = "" + height;
    attr.id = playerID;
    //console.log("embedding flash object with id "+playerID);

    //command to embed flash object
     try{
           swfobject.embedSWF(flashSrc, "no-flash", width, height,"9.0.0","",flashvars,params);
     }catch(err){
      // I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE
     }

     return true;
}
```

My code checks to see if the flash object has been written.  If it hasn't, it calls embed this.embedFlashPlayer() repeatedly in a while loop until the the div containing the swf can be found.  The trouble is that this just loops forever.  Any suggestion on what i can do in the try-catch block if swfobject is undefined?  I am 90% sure this is because my script loads faster and is running the embedSwfObject command before the library has loaded, but i may be wrong.  My script runs in $(function(){...}) command.  Any theories, suggestions, ideas as to how i can resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while` ...? Use `window.setInterval`:

```
...
    var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        //Code to check whether the object is ready or not.
        if($(that.mediaPlayer).find('#'+that.playerID).length){
             clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100); //Each 100ms = 10 times a second.
...
```

You're trying to use `while` for *polling*. `setInterval` is usually used instead of while, because (as you may have noticed), `while` causes the browser to "hang".

Comment: the problem with this solution is that after i call embedFlashObject i need to reference the flash object in the next line, and if i'm not mistaken, setInterval will just kick set the function to run in it's own 'thread', and my script will progress whether or not the flash object has been embedded.  I need a way to pause my script until the flash object has been found.

Comment: I took your advice and used set interval.  when i used it directly in place of hte while loop it failed like i htought it would.  Instead what i did is I wrapped the function that calls my script in "$(function(){...}" and wrapped that in window.setInterval and then followed your advice.  Thanks!